# Trace Debug ODP.NET produces no output when running RDL in Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, odp.net

I am trying to capture the SQL coming from an SSRS report that is connecting to an Oracle Database.

The ODP.net connector works, I am getting data back from the database.

However, after following [these instructions](https://blog.ilab8.com/2011/09/02/odp-net-pooling-and-connection-request-timed-out/) and the additional settings [mentioned here](https://allkindsofdatabasestuff.blogspot.com/2014/02/enabling-client-side-tracing-for-odpnet.html) for sqlnet.ora I still have no traces being produced.

I have tried adding the trace configs to 32 bit and 64 bit registry areas and to both dotNet 2.x and 4.  I have tried restarting my machine (in case registry settings were not being picked up).  I have added the sqlnet.ora settings (mentioned in the link) to both 32 and 64 bit clients.  I have literally tried everything I can think of to get this to work.  The TraceFileName is set to the [TEMP directory]/FileName so permissions should not be an issue.  I checked the event log, no errors there.

Anyone have any ideas?